# Kentico 8.2 Backend Web API Error

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

On one of our sides we get an error every time we log in to the backend of Kentico. Here is the event log message:

> **Event ID:** 1316868
>
> **Event type:** Error
>
> **Event time:** 8/3/2017 3:07:27 PM
>
> **Source:** WebApi
>
> **Event code:** NotAuthorized
>
> **User ID:** 65
>
> **User name:** public
>
> **IP address:** XX.X.XX.XXX
>
> **Description:** Unable to authorize the web API request. If you are running CMS on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, please ensure you
>   have Service Pack 1 installed.
>
> **Machine name:** ******
>
> **Event URL:** /cmsapi/WelcomeTile
>
> **URL referrer:** ********/CMSModules/ApplicationDashboard/ApplicationDashboard.aspx
>
> **User agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
>   Safari/537.36

Our Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Build 9600. The Kentico version we use is 8.2.49 and we tried also 8.2.50 but it changed nothing. We also have other sides on the server which running just fine. We also already tried to replace the Kentico files with a clean install but it has no effect... We guess there is some problem with the database because this is the only thing we not replaced yet as it is a big effort to do this.

May someone knows why we get this error?

Answer (score 0):

what authenticate modes are enable for the site/this subfolder? you need special authenticate modes for it to validate I believe.

did you follow the documentation exactly? often I find my issues are I missed a step.

Comment: I installed it the same way like every times. And as it is the normal Kentcio backend there should by no issues caused by my site running on it as the backend is not effected directly by my site, isn't it? 

Yes and it worked on the beginning but after a while I get this error for no clear reason. For this I guess there is some problems with the data in the database which cause my problems